# Помехи вместо сигнала stm32 nucleo-l053r8

Tags: c++, stm32, микроконтроллеры, arm

Есть код, генерируем треугольный сигнал и с помощью него гасим и зажигаем светодиод. Всё вроде прекрасно, но когда требуется вывести для дальнейшего считывания в Terminal с помощью команды printf, то прекрасный треугольный сигнал исчезает и появляется непрекрасная и некрасивая помеха, которая портит всю задачу.

Есть теория, что printf занимает слишком много времени, и отсюда вся проблема.

Плата nucleo-L053R8

```
#include "mbed.h"

#if !DEVICE_ANALOGOUT
#error You cannot use this example as the AnalogOut is not supported on this device.
#else
AnalogOut my_output(PA_4);
AnalogIn analog_value(A0);
DigitalOut led(LED1);
#endif

#define RANGE (0xFFFF)
#define BUFFER_SIZE (256)

void calculate_sinewave(void);

uint16_t buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

float meas_r,
    meas_v,
    AMPLITUDE = 0;

int main() {
    calculate_sinewave();
    
    while(1) {
        char test[BUFFER_SIZE];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
            float arg = buffer[i];
            my_output.write_u16(arg);
            meas_r = analog_value.read(); // Считать значение аналогового входа (значение от 0,0 до 1,0 = полный диапазон преобразования АЦП)
            meas_v = meas_r * 3300; // Преобразует значение в диапазоне 0В-3,3В

            sprintf(test, "measure = %f = %.0f mV %f \n\r", meas_r, meas_v, arg);
            //printf("measure = %f = %.0f mV %f \n\r", meas_r, meas_v, arg);

            if (meas_v < 400) {
                led = 0; // LED ON
            } else {
                led = 1; // LED OFF
            }
            
            wait_us(100);
        }
        //for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", test);
          //  printf("%s\n", test[i]);
        //}   
    }
}

void calculate_sinewave(void){
    for (int i = 0; i < (BUFFER_SIZE/2); i++) {
        AMPLITUDE+=(0.00244);
        buffer[i] = (uint16_t)(AMPLITUDE*RANGE);
    }
    for (int i = (BUFFER_SIZE/2) ; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
        AMPLITUDE-=(0.00244);
        buffer[i] = (uint16_t)(AMPLITUDE*RANGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Я то же не силен в микроконроллерах, но замечу, что если проблема действительно в времени выполнения printf (и да, он может быть не быстрым) то надо как то замерять сколько времени выполняются все операции одной итерации цикла и делать wait_us на 100-время_выполнения. Или если есть возможность ждать до определенного времени на каком нибудь таймере, то воспользоваться этим. Если есть подходящие прерывания по таймеру, то возможно выставить нужный период прерываний и делать всю работу в нем, перенеся printf в самый конец обработчика

Comment: wait_us пробовал выставлять разные значения "методом научного тыка" (дабы увидеть моргание светодиода (при 10us моргает слишком быстро, не видно, например)), но **такое ощущение**, что пока это всё в одном цикле, то абсолютно никак не влияет на сигнал. Пробовал и перед printf, и после, и в конце цикла.

Comment: @at0m Если вы программируете микроконтроллеры (особенно серии ARM CORTEX-M0) не используйте float этот CPU не поддерживает на аппаратном уровне float. Работа с float организовано программно. поэтому здесь очень большие  задержки.  И использование C++ тоже снижает производительность.

Comment: @Yaroslav Вы можете помочь с решением? Пробовал использовать `sprintf`, но смог вывести только ограниченное число значений

Comment: Картинка может "ломаться" если неправильно сделано согласование нагрузок.  Rн, и Cн - не должны выходить за границы определённых диапазонов (в документации описано). "Висячий" вывод может давать помехи. Провода должны быть максимально короткими. Возможно добавление повторителя напряжения на ОУ исправит картинку.

Comment: @at0m Попробуйте собрать проект используя [STM32CubeMX](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html) Ваша система сборки использует С++. Слишком много накладных расходов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ оказался очень прост: надо просто уменьшить частоту развёртки осциллографа, сигнал хоть и будет нарастать медленно, но сохранит свою форму
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]